# How to fetch an object from s3 based on a s3 Version using boto3 library?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have to fetch the version of an object after it is uploaded to a s3 bucket and store it in local mongo. After that I will have to use that version to fetch the object from s3. How to do this using boto3 library in python?. I have searched the documentation, but could not find any leads.

Comment: "uploaded to s3" uploaded how? You are uploading it using boto3? Exactly how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) accepts a `VersionId` argument. So you can use:

```
object = boto3.client("s3").get_object(
  Bucket="my-bucket",
  Key="my-key",
  VersionId="my-version",
)
```